# Can amended tax return filed before tax return cause errors?

Tags: united-states, taxes, irs, amended-tax-return

I'd like to ask about a notice I received from the IRS today. The notice requests more information about a certain line and correction of figures on a certain column on my 2013 amended tax return. I double checked for arithmetic, consistency, and accuracy, but all the figures seem to be correct. In addition, I checked copies of the documents I mailed and confirmed that I'd sent all necessary forms.

However, on my IRS record of account transcript, I noticed that swathes of numbers were filled in as "$0" where they shouldn't be. In addition, I saw that my amended tax return was filed and sent for processing in April and my original tax return was filed in June (nothing about processing).

Of course, I mailed the amended tax return after the original tax return. Is it possible that I got this notice as a result of the amended return somehow getting filed before the original return?

Answer (score 3):

Everything is possible. If you paper-filed there could be myriad of different issues that can cause problems. Bad OCR during the scan, someone missed a page, god knows what. That is why e-filing is much preferred - will be processed much faster and with way less possibilities for error. I think now you can e-file amended returns as well, not sure.

Specifically for you - I'd suggest contacting a licensed tax adviser (EA/CPA licensed in your State) and have them try and figure this out.

Generally, it is not advisable to send amended return before the original is processed, precisely to avoid such a confusion. If you sent the amended in April - why didn't you wait for the data before filing the original to begin with?

Comment: I appreciate the quick and thoughtful answer. I'll see if there's a tax adviser in my current location who can help. To answer your question, I had some income I'd forgot about and wanted to right the situation as quickly as possible.

Comment: @ImaginaryParakeet if you're living in a foreign country, it is very likely that using TurboTax etc is not for your benefit. Tax treaties, special treatment of foreign investments, FBAR, FATCA, PFIC, etc. Better shill out on a professional to do your taxes from abroad, will be cheaper in the long run.

Comment: (Sorry about the edit! For future readers, I used TurboTax, which doesn't allow filing for abroad.) I'll take a look around for an expat tax professional in my price range. Also, about your question, I had some income I'd forgotten about and wanted to right the situation as quickly as possible.